# $ is not defined in iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with an iframe in it. my iframe page is iframe.php and my main page is main.php when i load iframe.php directly my jquery code executes fine, but when I load main.php (which contains iframe.php as an iframe) I get an error "$ is not defined".

could this be because both main.php and iframe.php use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

if so how can I use jquery in the iframe page without including this line?

Comment: Is it possible that you have code in main.php outside of the iframe which is failing? Have you tried temporarily commenting out the frame and seeing whether the rest of the code on main.php works normally?

Comment: I know there are some issues with javacsript and iFrames relating to the parent document... I believe if the iFrame's source document is within the same domain as the parent document, then the iFrame inherites the javascript of the parent document, otherwise it does not. I have no idea if this is accurate... but my point is, what happens when you get rid of the jquery reference in the iframe doc?

Comment: When I comment out the iFrame the main.php page has no errors. it's weird when I remove all the javascript from iframe.php except the jquery include I get this error Error: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h, null) is null
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js
Line: 16

Comment: when i remove the jquery reference in the iframe i get the same error

Comment: Do you have an example of code that we can look at? It's a bit hard to envisage what you are saying with it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out. In the iFrame I used

```
var $ = parent.$;
```

as well as giving any jquery calls the document for context. ie

```
$("#element", document).doStuff();
```

It's weird because the original way I had it (with jquery included in both pages) worked fine in Safari for Mac but in Firefox it gave me the error

> Error: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h, null) is null Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js Line: 16

Answer (score 3):

I was loading iframe in a webpage and I could find $ object using

```
var $ = parent.$;
```

but this was not performing selection on the elements of iFrame. Found below code to execute selector on the iFrame body

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
    var iframeBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, iframeBody); };
    var $ = jQuery;
}
```

Somehow the document object was also `undefined`.

Source of above code: https://gist.github.com/843229

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Bad news-- you can't use Jquery unless it's in the document.  So, you're gonna have to load it regardless.

There's actually no harm in including the jquery call in both documents.  I have several clients who iFrame a portion of my company's app for marketing automation (which has it included) and also have Jquery included in their parent document, and it works just fine with no conflicts.  From a load standpoint, assuming you're setup correctly, the hit will be negligible due to caching.  So, include away.

Rule of thumb on iFrames...think of them as separate pages inside your page.  Yes, in some cases things carry over, but the document origin model prevents things like CSS from crossing between parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to newer version f.e. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js